# open_basedir issue on Fat-free framework

Tags: php, fat-free-framework, open-basedir

I have this following issue with open_basedir restrictions.

```
is_file(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/dev/bongos.com/vendor/bcosca/fatfree/lib/action/authaction.php) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/Dev/bongos.com/:/tmp/)
```

The reason why the case differs in the paths is because of a f3 method.

```
protected function autoload($class) {
    $class=$this->fixslashes(ltrim($class,'\\'));
    $func=NULL;
    if (is_array($path=$this->hive['AUTOLOAD']) &&
        isset($path[1]) && is_callable($path[1]))
        list($path,$func)=$path;
    foreach ($this->split($this->hive['PLUGINS'].';'.$path) as $auto)
        if ($func && is_file($file=$func($auto.$class).'.php') ||
            is_file($file=$auto.$class.'.php') ||
            is_file($file=$auto.strtolower($class).'.php') ||
            is_file($file=strtolower($auto.$class).'.php'))
            return require($file);
}
```

on the second last line it converts the path to lowercase to checks if it exists. If it does, it fails with the error mentioned.

There is no way I may disable open_basedir or manipulate any standard f3 code.

EDIT

My autoload looks like this.

```
AUTOLOAD= Apps/
```

Comment: What does your `AUTOLOAD` variable look like?

Comment: @xfra35 Thank you for looking. I have updated my question to include my autoload variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're calling the `Action\AuthAction` class, the framework autoloader is trying to find the 3 following files:

1. `Action/AuthAction.php` inside `PLUGINS`:
   `/home/Dev/bongos.com/vendor/bcosca/fatfree/lib/Action/AuthAction.php`
2. `action/authaction.php` inside `PLUGINS`:
   `/home/Dev/bongos.com/vendor/bcosca/fatfree/lib/action/authaction.php`
3. `action/authaction.php` inside lowercase `PLUGINS`:
   `/home/dev/bongos.com/vendor/bcosca/fatfree/lib/action/authaction.php`

The third attempt is throwing the `open_basedir` error. But that's just a side effect of the autoloader not finding the correct filepath. Without the `open_basedir` directive, you would have a `class not found` error.

If you make sure the class filename has the correct case (either `Action/AuthAction.php` or `action/authaction.php`), the autoloader should find the file.

However if you want to make sure the `open_basedir` doesn't mess with the autoloader in any situation, just set `PLUGINS` to `./`, which is a relative path pointing to `/home/Dev/bongos.com/vendor/bcosca/fatfree/lib/` by default (provided your application doesn't [change directory](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chdir.php)).